# Email not sent on Google Form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

My aim is every time a user submits a form. The form goes to a spreadsheet but also the contents get summarised and sent to two emails. Always the same emails.

```
  function myFunction() {
  function submitForm(e){
  // FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    message += (i + 1).toString() + '. ' + question + ': ' + answer + '\n';
   if(answer === 'English'){var send=1;}
   if(answer === 'Japanese'){var send=2;}
   if(answer === '身上異動届（結婚届）'){var send=3;}  
   if(answer === '住所・通勤経路'){var send=4;}     
  }

  var address1 = 'test1@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var address2 = 'test2@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var address3 = 'test3@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var title1 = '【氏名変更】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title2 = '【銀行口座変更】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title3 = '【身上異動届（結婚届）】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title4 = '【住所・通勤経路】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var content = 'The form was submitted with the following contents.\n\n' + message;
 
  var option = {};
  option.from = "info@gmail.com";
  
  if(send === 1){var to1 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to1, title1, content,option);}
  
  if(send === 2){var to2 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to2, title2, content,option);}
  
  if(send === 3){var to3 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to3, title3, content,option);}

  if(send === 4){var to4 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to4, title4, content,option);}
}
  }
}
```

But it seems that no email get sent.

I don't quite understand what's wrong

---

[Link to form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1O3lDzutI-hiXaH5yxjBifJuRYfu23ajqq50tMKgFVZA/edit?usp=sharing)

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q4nrN9VMB_aiNTrDQGNj7ryL2Fqtfw3PQRSD2bmMcX0/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Where is you `sendMail`?

Comment: Sorry,  forgot  to include it! Added it now

Comment: It seems you have one excessive closing brace `}` at the end of your code. Besides, where is `address3`?

Comment: If i remove it, i get "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input line: 42 file: Untitled.gs" - I added an extra } at the end (for a total of 3) and it seemed to fix but doesn't send any emails still. I edited the code to show

Comment: Not sure if it helps: the form's flow is as follows.

1q:Name,
2q:ID 
3q: english or japanese muli choice
Page 2: chose what option out of 5. 
page 3: fill in details and send
then it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the script at the right place.

Please newly create a script and then create the trigger from the script editor of the form.

Reference:

[Creating a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script)

You could found your trigger is different from [jcb01's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823244/16125139)

---

[image]

---

```js
function submitForm(e){
  // FormApp.getActiveForm()
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    message += (i + 1).toString() + '. ' + question + ': ' + answer + '\n';
   if(answer === 'English'){var send=1;}
   if(answer === 'Japanese'){var send=2;}
   if(answer === '身上異動届（結婚届）'){var send=3;}  
   if(answer === '住所・通勤経路'){var send=4;}     
  }

  var address1 = 'test1@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var address2 = 'test2@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var address3 = 'test3@gmail.com'; //★Your Email Address
  var title1 = '【氏名変更】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title2 = '【銀行口座変更】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title3 = '【身上異動届（結婚届）】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title4 = '【住所・通勤経路】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var content = 'The form was submitted with the following contents.\n\n' + message;
 
  var option = {};
  option.from = "info@gmail.com";
  
  console.log(send, content);

  if(send === 1){var to1 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to1, title1, content,option);}
  
  if(send === 2){var to2 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to2, title2, content,option);}
  
  if(send === 3){var to3 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to3, title3, content,option);}

  if(send === 4){var to4 = [address1, address2, address3];
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to4, title4, content,option);}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping! I deleted the whole script and trigger, created a new one (with what you pasted last time). Still nothing. The trigger is myFunction. I can't chose any other trigger

Comment: Please save the script before you try to create a trigger. Please be specific what is your problem.

Comment: The script is as you see. The problem is, once the script is saved and the trigger is created there should be a mail being sent with the summarised contents of the submitted form. That isn't the case, and that's the problem. The script is aiming to pull the data and send it in an email.

Comment: No, it should work. I have added a screenshot which is the log upon submits of a simplified version of your form. The beginning number is the value of `send`.

Comment: Are you using the two documents I provided? I haven't received anything in any of my emails. I deleted all scripts, made a new script. Added my emails in place of the test@gmail.coms, added a trigger. Sent a form - no emails were received.

Comment: No, I copied and tested it myself. Please create the script, create the trigger and test yourself.

Comment: Can you once again paste the code? I may be pasting the wrong code but I've tried every single code submitted and none of them are doing what you said has succeeded

Comment: Added. It is the same as my previous answer but I added a log line.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what's wrong. I deleted previous script, deleted previous trigger, added new script (copy and paste of your script), added new trigger. Save & Run - this error popped up TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined

Comment: Are you doing everything **from the script editor of the form but not that of spreadsheet**? Please share a screenshot of the details of your trigger.

Comment: I'm doing it from the spreadsheet. Should I switch to the form's script editor? I added a screenshot my question

Comment: As I told you do it from the form.

Comment: Please read our answers and follow the instructions.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

from triggers menu set a trigger to run "your script" immediately on form submission
[image: select trigger menu -create a new trigger]

[image: choose your function , from form, onform submit,notify me immediately]

Comment: This was already set up (and I delete the trigger when I try any suggestions just incase)

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitForm(e) {
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var message = '';
  let send = '';
  const option = {from:"info@gmail.com"};
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    message += (i + 1).toString() + '. ' + question + ': ' + answer + '\n';
    if (answer == 'English') { send = 1; }
    if (answer == 'Japanese') { send = 2; }
    if (answer == '身上異動届（結婚届）') { send = 3; }
    if (answer == '住所・通勤経路') { send = 4; }
  }
  var address1 = 'test1@gmail.com';
  var address2 = 'test2@gmail.com'; 
  var address3 = 'test3@gmail.com'; 
  var title1 = '【氏名変更】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title2 = '【銀行口座変更】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title3 = '【身上異動届（結婚届）】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var title4 = '【住所・通勤経路】Someone has submitted a form.';
  var content = 'The form was submitted with the following contents.\n\n' + message;
  if (send == 1) {
    var to1 = [address1, address2, address3];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(to1, title1, content, option);
  }

  if (send == 2) {
    var to2 = [address1, address2, address3];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(to2, title2, content, option);
  }

  if (send == 3) {
    var to3 = [address1, address2, address3];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(to3, title3, content, option);
  }

  if (send == 4) {
    var to4 = [address1, address2, address3];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(to4, title4, content, option);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what went wrong. This error is popping up with this code TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined

Comment: I hope you are not try to run the function from the script editor without supply a proper event object.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. All the code and info is there. a form exists, a spreadsheet exists, a trigger exists.

Comment: You said you were getting an error.  I wanted to know if you tried running the function without a proper event object.  You have not responded.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean and provide an example of an event object?

Comment: The simplest way is to do a submit from your form.

Comment: You can get a copy of the event object by inserting this line after the function declaration.  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));  As far as an explanation the function presumably was designed to run under the onFormSubmit trigger.  That trigger supplies the event object but many people often mistakenly think that they can run the function without supply the event object which results in the type of error you have received.  Thats why I asked the queestion.  If you've done that then the error occurred because you did not supply a proper event object.  In this case the event object is complex

Comment: After every edit, i submit a form to check if I get the notification @idfurw

Comment: I added that line, that didn't change anything. I still don't understand what you mean by event object but there is a form that exists that I trial after editing the code. That form feeds into a spreadsheet where this code has been added (in the script editor). That sheet has been getting updated after every submission & the triggers are always set up for form submission, notify immediately etc.

Comment: That line wasn't there to fix a problem is was placed there to show you the event object.  You need to go view executions to see the logger output.

Comment: You really should spend so time learning about the Logger Class.  It's an important debug tool.

Comment: Since changing to this version (code above), the executions say failed.

Comment: Open the top one up and look inside.  Maybe you can paste the info into your questions so that we can all see it.

Comment: Thank you for the time you've invested and helped but I don't quite understand what you're suggesting and why it's not sending any emails. I'll switch to the code that the others were suggesting as it didn't show any problems except not sending the email

Comment: Did you get the JSON for the event object?